# Json with C# and Mono

Tags: c#, json, mono, json.net

I'm trying to read a json string into memory and get this undocumented error msg

```
$ mcs -r:FortnoxAPILibrary.dll -r:npgsql.dll -r:System.Data.dll -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll Vouchers.cs 
Vouchers.cs(44,18): error CS0103: The name `JArray' does not exist in the current context
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

My code is

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");

var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  
foreach(JObject root in objects)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
    {
        var appName = app.Key;
        var description = (String)app.Value["Description"];
        var value = (String)app.Value["Value"];

        Console.WriteLine(appName);
        Console.WriteLine(description);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

Where is it documented how this should work?

Comment: Here it is documented that in which namespace it should be: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more than likely missing a using statement.

`using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

Every piece of C# code you write, except for core types, requires a using statement pointing to any dependencies.

C# libraries often don't document the using statement requirements for a block of code. Maybe an oversight, but most users are using an IDE, which warns of the missing statement and offers options to automatically insert them.

[image: IDE Hints]

Comment: Yeah, where is that MCVE? There is none.

Answer (score 0):

It is not documented that I must include this line.

`using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`